# $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{(\sin x)^a}{x^b}dx=?,\,\text{suppose} \ a,b \in \mathbb{Z^+},a-b\geq 0,b\geq 2$

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{(\sin x)^a}{x^b}dx=?,\,\text{suppose} \ a,b  \in \mathbb{Z^+},a-b\geq 0,b\geq 2$$
I know how to calculate if $a-b\equiv 0 \pmod 2$，but I don't know
what to do when $a-b \equiv 1\pmod 2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ be a positive integer, and define $I(b)$ for complex $b$ by the following improper integral:

$$ I(b) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(\sin x)^a}{x^b} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

This integral converges for $b \in \mathcal{D}_a$, where

$$ \mathcal{D}_a = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \mathbf{1}_{\{2 \mid a\}} < \operatorname{Re}(z) < a+1 \} $$

and $\mathbf{1}_{\{2 \mid a\}}$ is the indicator function for the condition $2 \mid a$, so that $\mathbf{1}_{\{2 \mid a\}} = 1 $ if $a$ is even and $\mathbf{1}_{\{2 \mid a\}} = 0$ if $a$ is odd.

Now, to evaluate $I(b)$, we invoke the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** For $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$ and $1 < \operatorname{Re}(b) < 2$,
>
> $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i\xi x} - 1}{x^b} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi  b) \Gamma (b)} (-i\xi)^{b-1}. $$

We defer the proof to the end and demonstrate how this lemma helps evaluate $I(b)$.

**Step 1.** Assume for a moment that $1 < b < 2$. Then

\begin{align*}
I(b)
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^b} \left(\frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^a \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{(2i)^a} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^b} \sum_{k=0}^{a} (-1)^k \binom{a}{k} e^{i(a-2k)x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{(2i)^a} \sum_{k=0}^{a} (-1)^k \binom{a}{k} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i(a-2k)x} - 1}{x^b} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{1}{(2i)^a} \frac{\pi}{\sin (\pi  b) \Gamma (b)}  \sum_{k=0}^{a} (-1)^k \binom{a}{k} (i(2k-a))^{b-1}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{2^a \sin (\pi  b) \Gamma (b)} \sum_{k=0}^{a} \binom{a}{k} i^{2k-a} (i(2k-a))^{b-1}.
\end{align*}

Moreover, since $b$ is real,

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Re} \left[ i^{2k-a} (i(2k-a))^{b-1} \right]
&= |2k-a|^{b-1} \operatorname{Re} \left[ i^{2k-a} i^{(b-1)\operatorname{sgn}(2k-a)}  \right] \\
&= |2k-a|^{b-1} \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2} (|2k-a| + b-1) \right) \\
&= |2k-a|^{b-1} \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} (|2k-a| + b) \right)
\end{align*}

Now, since $I(b)$ is real-valued for $1 < b < 2$, we have $I(b) = \operatorname{Re}[I(b)]$. Then plugging the above observation to the summation representation of $I(b)$, we obtain

\begin{align*}
\bbox[padding:5px; border:1px dotted navy; color:navy;]{
I(b)
= \frac{\pi}{2^a \sin (\pi  b) \Gamma (b)} \sum_{k=0}^{a} \binom{a}{k} |2k-a|^{b-1} \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} (|2k-a| + b) \right).
} \tag{1}
\end{align*}

**Step 2.** Now, we release hold of $b$ and allow it to take values in all of $\mathcal{D}_a$. Then it is not hard to show that $I(b)$ defines an analytic function on $\mathcal{D}_a$. Moreover, the right-hand side (RHS) of $\text{(1)}$ as a function of $b$ is meromorphic on $\mathcal{D}_a$ and coincides with $I(b)$ on the set $(1, 2)$. So, by the identity function theorem, $\text{(1)}$ becomes an identity between meromorphic functions in $b \in \mathcal{D}_a$.

Moreover, since $I(b)$ is holomorphic on $\mathcal{D}_a$, the same is true for the RHS of $\text{(1)}$. This means that each pole candidate $b \in \mathcal{D}_a \cap \mathbb{Z}$ induced by $\frac{1}{\sin(\pi b)}$ is canceled out, reducing to a removable singularity.

Consequently, if $b \in \mathcal{D}_a \cap \mathbb{Z}$, then

\begin{align*}
I(b)
&= \lim_{\tilde{b} \to b} I(\tilde{b}) \\[0.5em]
&= \begin{cases}
\displaystyle \frac{(-1)^b}{2^a (b-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{a} \binom{a}{k} |2k-a|^{b-1} \cdot (-1)^{\frac{|2k-a| + b - 1}{2}}  \log|2k-a|, 
& \text{$a+b$ is odd,} \\[0.5em]
\displaystyle \frac{(-1)^b}{2^a (b-1)!} \sum_{k=0}^{a} \binom{a}{k} |2k-a|^{b-1} \cdot (-1)^{\frac{|2k-a| + b}{2}} \frac{\pi}{2}, 
& \text{$a+b$ is even,} 
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

with the convention that $0 \log 0 = 0$.

---

**Appendix - Proof of Lemma.** Let $1 < b < 2$ and $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$. Then by the standard machinery in [Abelian theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_and_Tauberian_theorems#Abelian_theorems), it is routine to prove that

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i\xi x} - 1}{x^b} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i\xi x} - 1}{x^b} \cdot e^{-\epsilon x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} (J(\epsilon - i\xi) - J(\epsilon)),
\end{align*}

where $J(z)$ is defined by

$$ J(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-zx} - 1}{x^b} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Now suppose $\operatorname{Re}(z) > 0$. Then by integration by parts,

\begin{align*}
J(z)
&= \frac{-z}{b-1} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{1-b} e^{-zx} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{-z}{b-1} \cdot \frac{\Gamma(2-b)}{z^{2-b}} \\
&= -\frac{\Gamma(2-b)\Gamma(b-1)}{\Gamma(b)} z^{b-1} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi b)\Gamma(b)} z^{b-1}.
\end{align*}

Plugging this back, the assertion of the lemma is obtained, completing the proof.

---

**Addendum.** Below is a Mathematica code that implements the above formula for *integer* $b$.

```
(* Change the following values: *)
a = 5;
b = 4;
(* Formula *)
Simplify[
 If[OddQ[a + b],
  (-1)^b/(2^a Gamma[b])
    Sum[(-1)^((Abs[2 k - a] + b - 1)/2) Binomial[a, k] Abs[2 k - a]^(
     b - 1) If[2 k == a, 0, Log[Abs[2 k - a]]], {k, 0, a}],
  (-1)^b/(2^a Gamma[b])
    Sum[(-1)^((Abs[2 k - a] + b)/2) Binomial[a, k] Abs[2 k - a]^(
     b - 1) Pi/2, {k, 0, a}]
  ]
 ]
```

For example, the screenshot below tests this code for $a = 5$ and $b = 4$:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you for your exquisite answer！